# How do I add this entry?

Tags: repository

I am having issues adding this entry to my repository list!

`sudo apt-add-repository "http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/"` isn't working.

[image]

The following results in an error:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu"

Err http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca precise/main Sources 404  Not Found
```

and also the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/"

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/precise//precise/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

and also the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu precise"

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/precise/precise/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

editing the sources.list manually gives the error:

```
"http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/"

W: GPG error: http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca precise/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The package *r-cran-rjags* is contained in the official precise repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/r-cran-rjags

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu/
```

The resulting entry will look like:

```
$ tail /etc/apt/sources.list
...
deb http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty main
```

I am on 14.04, so `trusty` was automatically added. If you are on 12.04, `precise` will be added instead of `trusty`.

The last error indicates that your entry is correct, but you haven't added the repository key. From the [README](http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu/README):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```